# NodeJs async await not waiting correctly in for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I have a loop inside my async function which essentially is meant to solve captchas, however the awaits within the loop don't seem to be working...

Here is what the loop looks like:

```
for(var i=0; i < 7; i++){
      fileName = `./tasks/myfile-${i.toString()}.json`

      // SOLVE reCAPTCHAs
      const requestId = await initiateCaptchaRequest(apiKey);
      const response = await pollForRequestResults(apiKey, requestId);
      console.log(`SOLVED CAPTCHA - ${response}`);

      // Should run this function AFTER the response has been received
      await enter(response);
}
```

And here is what the functions look like that the loop utilises to solve the captcha (code from: https://medium.com/@jsoverson/bypassing-captchas-with-headless-chrome-93f294518337):

```
async function initiateCaptchaRequest(apiKey) {
  const formData = {
    method: 'userrecaptcha',
    googlekey: siteDetails.sitekey,
    key: apiKey,
    pageurl: siteDetails.pageurl,
    json: 1
  };
  const response = await request.post('http://2captcha.com/in.php', {form: formData});
  return JSON.parse(response).request;
}

async function pollForRequestResults(key, id, retries = 30, interval = 1500, delay = 15000) {
  await timeout(delay);
  return poll({
    taskFn: requestCaptchaResults(key, id),
    interval,
    retries
  });
}

function requestCaptchaResults(apiKey, requestId) {
  const url = `http://2captcha.com/res.php?key=${apiKey}&action=get&id=${requestId}&json=1`;
  return async function() {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
      const rawResponse = await request.get(url);
      const resp = JSON.parse(rawResponse);
      if (resp.status === 0) return reject(resp.request);
      resolve(resp.request);
    });
  }
}

const timeout = millis => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis))
```

My problem is that the loop seen above should run the **initiateCaptchaRequest** function which gets the requestId, **THEN** run the **pollForRequestResults** function to get the response and **THEN** run the **enter** function.

But right now the awaits don't seem to be working and almost instantly after the initiateCaptchaRequest function is run, the pollForRequestResults function runs which returns a JSON parse error obviously because the requestId has not been gathered yet, and is used in the requestCaptchaResults function...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could You provide working example of any sort ???

Comment: @SkorpEN A working example is linked in the post

Comment: It is not working example. Working example is your project hosted somewhere or use code example to show your problem. Pointing to web article is not a working example. It is just problem description. You could sometimes find working example in author github, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your issue, but it seem to work perfectly fine for me. But I think the issue is in **requestCaptchaResults** function

```
(async ()=>{
 for(var i=0; i < 7; i++){
     await initiateCaptchaRequest(i);
     console.log(i)
 }
})()

function initiateCaptchaRequest(i){
  console.log('sdas'+i);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{resolve();}, 4000);
  });
}
```

output:

```
sdas0
0
sdas1
1
sdas2
2
sdas3
3
sdas4
4
sdas5
5
sdas6
6
```

Answer (score 0):

await is not works in for loop because for loop is not async

so you have to make for loop to promise

```
const newFunc = ()=>{
     return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{

        // SOLVE reCAPTCHAs
      const requestId = await initiateCaptchaRequest(apiKey);
      const response = await pollForRequestResults(apiKey, requestId);
      console.log(`SOLVED CAPTCHA - ${response}`);

      // Should run this function AFTER the response has been received
      const data = await enter(response);
      resolve(data);
     })
}

Yourfunction(){
val = []
for(var i=0; i < 7; i++){
       fileName = `./tasks/myfile-${i.toString()}.json`
      val.push(**your arguments)
}
return new Promise.all(val).then((res)=>{return res;}).catch((err)=> {return err;})

}
```